# Azure WebApp + SignalR + .net core + blazor (StatusCode: 405 'Method Not Allowed')

Tags: azure, .net-core, signalr, azure-web-app-service, blazor

I'm having issues with a SignalR project I'm currently working on. I'm trying to build a server using .Net Core, and a client using Blazor.

Building in local i can use signalR.

Publishing the webapp into Azure I've an error 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed' in signalR  negotiate.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdGZO.png)

I've configured Cors in the .net core app and in the azure web app and activated the web socket.

.net core Startup:
[Startup.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAdu0.png)
[Startup.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4jfY.png)

Azure Cors:
[Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuxUC.png)

Thank you!!

Comment: Edited! In the startup.cs i've configured cors policy. Thanks

Comment: No, do not link to your code but post it here (abbreviated if necessary).

Comment: @Ale_Bianco, you're code, though minimal, seems to be functional. But are you enabling CORS on the server side; that is, an Asp.Net core that hosts your Blazor app ? If not, you should configure CORS on the server side app, not the front end...

Comment: @Issac thanks for your answer. I've enabled cors on the server side not in the front end...